# C#: web browser control, problem with cache

Tags: c#, caching, webbrowser-control, refresh

I am using a web browser control do display some data in html form. Data comes from the database. The browser is inside a dialogbox, and every time the data are changed, the dialog is displayd. The problem is that it is displayed with the old values, even if it is bind with the updated object/datasourse.

Now I use a refresh button to refresh the web browser control and call the Refresh() method. But this is not what I want. I need to see the changed data on the load of the dialog box.

Does this control have any method to clear its cache?

Thnx in advance.

Comment: Say the url of the html "data.htm", you could on every load add a querystring, likq "data.htm?v=1", "data.htm?v=2", forcing it to reaload.

Comment: This does not resolve the problem. The new object is reloaded, but the webbrowsercontroler when its reload does not display the new data but displays the old data.